# Google Drive API - more than one hit for a single notification

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

I have created a channel which is created successfully

```
public static Channel CreateChannel(DriveService service,string ChannelGuid)
    {
        var pageToken = service.Changes.GetStartPageToken().Execute();
        Channel ch = new Channel();
        ch.Id = ChannelGuid;
        ch.Type = "web_hook";
        ch.Address = "https://abcd.efgh.com/home/SyncGoogleDoc"; //dummy url
        var result = service.Changes.Watch(ch, pageToken.StartPageTokenValue).Execute();
        return result;
    }
```

and when any file added, update, delete from the googlr drive api i got notification as well

Once I receive a change notification I echo '200' string, as it is recommended in Google Drive API reference:

but problem i am getting notifications twice for each add/update call
and i need to run a sync job which start syncing my files twice

What possibily i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you accidently created the channel twice? See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels): `When a channel is close to its expiration, you must create a new one by calling the watch method. As always, you must use a unique value for the id property of the new channel. Note that there is likely to be an "overlap" period of time when the two notification channels for the same resource are active.`

Comment: I was also assuming that there are multiple channels. but I have checked and create a single channel explicitly to check this scenario.
it was still sending 2 notifications